# Synapse:CopyActivity,Upsert option:The data type xml cannot be used as operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it not comparable

Tags: azure-synapse

Synapse:CopyActivity,Upsert option:The data type xml cannot be used as operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it not comparable
In database i checked sink table have 2 xml column so i am getting error. How to over come this error. I dont want to change datatype in table.

Comment: Please only use the tag [tag:azure-pipelines] for questions about the Azure DevOps Pipelines offering. When choosing tags, take a moment to review the tag summary to see whether it is appropriate for your question or not.

Comment: Consider using a stored procedure sink to implement your more complicated logic.  You could cast your XML as a string for the comparison only but XML is a complex type so you probably shouldn't be comparing it in this way.  Alternatively, consider landing your source data into a table with the Copy activity and using a Stored Proc activity to process it.

Answer (score 0):

I used script activity in synapse to cast xml data to varchar in each table and then to union all the tables.
Then I copied the data to target table which has xml data type using copy activity. Below are the steps.,

- Source table and target table has xml data type column
  [image: Tables with xml data type before union]
- Use the below script in script activity for dynamically converting all xml  data to varchar.

> ```
> Declare @column_list varchar(max)
> Set @column_list = (
> SELECT  
>   STUFF((SELECT  ',' + case when system_type_id= 241  then 'Cast(' +  name + ' as nvarchar(max)) as ' + name Else name End FROM sys.columns SCI
>             WHERE   SCI.object_id =SCO.object_id 
>             ORDER BY column_id 
>         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS 'a'
> FROM sys.columns SCO where object_id = object_id('table1') 
> group by object_id) 
>   
> Declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''
> Set @sql = 'Drop table if exists union_stg_table; Select  * into union_stg_table From (
> Select ' + @column_list + ' From table1
> union
> Select ' + @column_list + ' From table2
> union 
> Select ' + @column_list + ' From table3
> )A'
> exec sp_executesql @sql
> ```

[image: Script activity]

- Copy the script activity's output table into the target table using copy activity. Target table has xml data type.

[image: result table]

As wbob-MSFT has suggested, you can also use stored procedure for transformation. Similarly, we can use intersection, except statements between two tables with the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

XML data type is not supported in synapse

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-tables-data-types#unsupported-data-types